# how to calculate percentage of counts in sql

Tags: sql

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? This is the best i can do but i don't think it's correct.

```
With
(select Count(distinct(follower_account_id) as followers
 From pw_social_relation)
Select count(distinct(follower_account_id))/followers
From pw_social_relation
Where count(followee_account_id)>=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this query will work for you.

```
select ((b.result/a.total)*100) as percentage from 
(select count(distinct(follower_account_id)) as total from pw_social_relation) a
,(select count(follower_account_id) as result from pw_social_relation group by follower_account_id having count(*) >= 3) b;
```

I have not executed this but this is the idea if how can you solve the given problem.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT follower_account_id, (COUNT(distinct(followee_account_id))/@totalfollowers) * 100 as followersPer
 From pw_social_relation
 GROUP BY follower_account_id
 HAVING Count(distinct(followee_account_id)) >= 3

Answer (score 0):

Count followings first, then count accounts with at least three of them.

Anyway, while this looks correct on first glance ...

```
select
  count(case when following >= 3 then 1 end) / count(*) as percentage
from
(
  select follower_account_id, count(*) as following
  from pw_social_relation
  group by follower_account_id
) counted;
```

... I think we can surmise that there can be accounts not following anybody. So we must compare with the number of accounts in some account table instead. But from here it'll be easy for you to adjust the query accordingly :-)